# Firefox-only lwc error when console is open (Spring '21 update)

Tags: lightning-web-components, firefox, spring21

Today I found my scratch org updated with a new critical bug.

I have a lwc page containing a plethora of other lwc components, which would be quite a mess to debug file-after-file. It works fine on Linux x64 Chromium and Opera. It worked fine on firefox **until the Spring '21** update.

### Bug

Bug behaviour is as follow: Upon loading of the page (firefox, dev console opened), everything works fine, until the first time the user **clicks** in the webpage. An error modal appears, with **A Component Error has occurred** as its heading.
Message is: `[t is undefined]`. Component descriptor is: `markup://app_flexipage:lwcAppFlexipageInternal`. Error is raised by:

`https://static.lightning.force.com/cs18/auraFW/javascript/8WYDoRiNKzw4em08r-Gg4A/aura_prod.js`,
function `callHook`, line 37, col 72404.
[Here is the whole stack trace (pastebin)](https://pastebin.com/PhzBAACZ)

It's important to note that **this bug triggers only when firefox's dev console is opened**. No action is required in the dev console to reproduce the bug, and it does so on a fresh install of firefox. Also the **stack trace does not contain a custom component**, it's all base app in the stack trace. Unfortunately, debug mode is not an option.
Also, to be clear, when I talk about the dev console, I am talking about the firefox development tool you can open with F12, I am NOT talking about the salesforce developer console.

According to [this question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/332249/things-to-look-out-for-in-spring-21) there shouldn't be any breaking change of the sort. According to [Salesforce's Spring '21 release document](https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/230/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_spring21_release_notes.pdf) there shouldn't be a special setup necessary for firefox, indicating there shouldn't be any browser-specific major bug.
Any ideas or pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After more digging on this bug I have an answer:

A component inside had an onclik event targetting an unwritten method.

```
onclick={handleMenuEvent}
```

Where `handleMenuEvent` is undefined. On any other browser this fails silently. On firefox with dev console opened it raises an error. Something should be done in aura_prod to render the behaviour consistent one way or another.

**TL;DR**: check your events and that all methods mentioned in the HTML are defined in the JS.